# Conditional Formatting to change color 30 days prior to expiry date in column

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, json-formatting

I am trying to update conditional formatting of a column to change color to red, when expiration date in the column is 30 days prior to expiring.

Answer (score 1):

Open the column formatting pane --> open the drop-down menu under 'ExpiryDate' column --> Under Column Settings, choose Format this column --> Under Format Columns, use below JSON.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "debugMode": true,
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "=if([$ExpiryDate] - 2592000000 <= @now , '#ff0000','')"
  }
}
```

For a day, add milliseconds (24*60*60*1000 = 86,400,000). You need to add 30 days so (30*24*60*60*1000 = 2,592,000,000).

Also, here the ***ExpiryDate*** is the internal name of the column.

The red color will be applied to all the expired items and an item whose expiry is within the next 30 days.

For more reference, please refer [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting).